# $f(f(x))= \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k[f(x)]^k \implies f(x)=$?

Tags: polynomials

let $n\ge 1,n\in N,a_{i}\in R,i=0,1,2,\cdots,n-1$,and the function $f(x)\in C[x] $ such at

$$f(f(x))=[f(x)]^n+a_{n-1}[f(x)]^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}f(x)+a_{0}$$

find n times polynomial
 $f(x)=?$

my idea: let $f(x)=b_{n}x^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_{1}x+b_{0},b_{i}\in C,i=0,1,2,\cdots,n$

then  $f(f(x))=b_{n}(b_{n}x^n+\cdots+b_{0})^n+b_{n-1}(b_{n}x^n+\cdots+b_{0})^{n-1}+\cdots+b_{0}=(b_{n}x^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_{0})^n+a_{n-1}(b_{n}x^n+\cdots+b_{0})^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}(b_{n}x^n+\cdots+b_{0})+b_{0}$

then we have

$$b^{n+1}_{n}=b^n_{n}$$ then $b_{n}=0$ or$ b_{n}=1$

then we have

$$ b_{n-1}(x^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_{0})^{n-1}+\cdots+b_{0}=a_{n-1}(x^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_{0})^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}(x^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_{0})+a_{0}$$
then we have 
 $b_{n-1}=a_{n-1}$

then we can't any idea.

Comment: Hint: any non-constant complex polynomial is surjective as a complex-valued function. In particular, there are $n+1$ distinct points in the range of $f$.

Comment: Is the following restatement correct? Given is a monic polynomial $p\in\Bbb C[x]$ of degree $n$, and we are looking for polynomials $f\in\Bbb C[x]$ of degree $n$ such that $f(f(x))=p(f(x))$ for all $x\in\Bbb C$. What are all possible solutions for $f$?